# Return List to ajax mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on ***MVC3*** and following is my controller

```
  public List<int> ddlTransType_Change(int DocID)
        {

            return UserDocumentServive.getSelectedUsers(DocID);

        }
```

My ***Ajax***

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/MIS.MVC/" + "DocumentApproval/ddlTransType_Change",
                data: {
                    'DocID': $("#ddlTransType").val().trim()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.value)
},
error: function (e) {
                    alert("Error:Unable to load data from server");
                }
            });
```

Controller returns a list of int values i.e `{1,74,23,1}` and I want to show them in alert.
any idea how to do it .?

Comment: Have u debugged in browser what result contains

Comment: Is it an `ApiController` or a regular `Controller`?

Comment: result contain a string System.generic..... bla bla

Comment: I'm confused. Seems like result is a list of ints, not a string. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using MVC3, its better to return json data back to your ajax success call

```
public ActionResult ddlTransType_Change(int DocID)
    {

         List<int> list = UserDocumentServive.getSelectedUsers(DocID);;
        return Json(new
        {
            list = list
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Then your ajax call changes to

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/MIS.MVC/" + "DocumentApproval/ddlTransType_Change",
                data: {'DocID': $("#ddlTransType").val().trim()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                                           var list=result.list;
              $.each( list, function( index, value )
                                         {
                                            alert(value);
                                           });
                                             },
error: function (e) {
                    alert("Error:Unable to load data from server");
                }
        });
```

Comment: But its only 15.42 hahahha ;)

Comment: @Nitinvarpe i add the above code but it shows alert from error function "Error:Unable to load data from server". i dnt know where is the problem

Comment: [InvalidOperationException]: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Comment: Check update add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet to returning json